# mlflow ui doesn't show logged runs of my keras model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, mlflow

I created a sample keras model, and use mlflow.tensorflow.autolog() to track my model. However, the logged runs are not appeared in mlflow ui.
[image]

```
mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()

#setting hyper parameters
batch_size = 10
epochs = 100
optimizer = 'adam'
loss = 'binary_crossentropy'

def create_classifier():
    classifier = tf.keras.Sequential()
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 12))
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier

classifier = create_classifier()
classifier.summary()

classifier.fit(X_train.to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy(), batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs,verbose = 1)

score, acc = classifier.evaluate(X_train.to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy(), batch_size=batch_size)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test.to_numpy())
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

print('*'*20)
score, acc = classifier.evaluate(X_test.to_numpy(), y_test.to_numpy(),
                            batch_size=batch_size)
# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

I got following warning when I call autolog
[image]

The output when I fit the model with training data:
[image]

What do I need to do in order to make the run available in mlflow ui?

Note: MlFlow doc states that it only compatible with tensorflow >=2.3 and my tensorflow is 2.10.1.

update:
I found there are 2 /mlruns directories in my project, one located where my python code located as you can see in the screen clip, "ml-flow-project-example2/model/mlruns", and another one located at "ml-flow-project-example2/venv/Scripts/mlruns". However, the /mlruns in venv is empty. But it is where the mlflow.exe located. If I move the directory "7c10db034cdd47dfbba12885da25ff0f" from /model/mlruns to venv/Scripts/mlruns, the run will appear in mlflow ui.

Is there anyway to let mlflow ui point to the correct mlruns directory?

[image]

[image]